# Updating the content of a text field using AHK

Tags: csv, automation, autohotkey

I am trying to update the `txtAddressSearchSingleField` at http://www.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/demos/address-finder/ with a postcode from a csv file. So far I've tried the below:

```
fileread, AddressList, mk-data-000001-1.csv

IE := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
ComObjError(false)
IE.Visible := true

loop, parse, AddressList, `n, `r
{
    PostCode := A_LoopField
    IE.Navigate("http://www.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/demos/address-finder/")
    IE.document.getElementById("txtAddressSearchSingleField").value := PostCode
}
;IE.quit()
```

**mk-data-000001-1.csv sample data**

```
MK4 4FL
MK46 5EF
MK2 2RD
MK12 5EG
MK13 7BX
```

But it doesn't seem to be working - any idea why?

Comment: have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10258397/1282023).

Answer (score 0):

```
FileRead, AddressList, mk-data-000001-1.csv

IE := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
ComObjError(false)
IE.Visible := true

Loop, Parse, AddressList, `n, `r
{
    PostCode := A_LoopField
    IE.Navigate("http://www.postcodeanywhere.co.uk/demos/address-finder/")
    While IE.readyState != 4 || IE.document.readyState != "complete" || IE.busy
        Sleep, 25
    IE.document.getElementById("txtAddressSearchSingleField").focus() ;ususally you don't need this, in this case the value won't be visible if you don't do this, but it will still be there.
    IE.document.getElementById("txtAddressSearchSingleField").value := PostCode
}
;IE.quit()
```

The main issue is, that you have to wait for the page to load, to reliably interact with it. The second "issue" is that the input field content doesn't show it's actual value unless you click it before or after changing the value. A simple call of .focus() fixes this imperfection.