# VBA - Internet Explorer Automization - Pressing a Button

Tags: javascript, vba, internet-explorer, automation

I'm trying to automate a web page in VBA. This is the online bank system. I try to get a Transaction History export in .csv file. Everything works OK. When it comes to the final <kbd>Export</kbd> button, it fails.
Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screen Shot]

The code that I use in VBA to click this is:

```
Set IEApp = New InternetExplorer

IEApp.Document.getElementByName("j_idt49:j_idt61").Click
```

From this i get :

> Run time Error '438':  Object doesn't support ths property or method

The  HTML code behind this is :

```
<input type="submit" name="j_idt49:j_idt61" value="Export">
```

For few days i try different solutions, but all fail.
Any idea on how to automate pressing this button ?
Thanks.

Comment: Coz `Click` should be a function, maybe?

Comment: It looks like it is a function that is dynamically assigned to the button. After few days of debuging, i couldn't find it. Any help is higly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this was to add a .focus call before the .click .
So :

```
Set IEApp = New InternetExplorer
IEApp.Document.getElementByName("j_idt49:j_idt61").focus
IEApp.Document.getElementByName("j_idt49:j_idt61").Click
```

I found the solution to my problem: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191506/internet-explorer-automation-with-vba-input-events?rq=1)
There is an explanation also.

Regards.