# Click on the a href when the btn is named the same everywhere

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find out how I can click on the following button as they are all named the same.  As you can see the button is named "btn-default" twice, but I need to click on the one which contains Cloud.

The following code HTML which is a source of an internal website that I need to use for my VB application. Basically, this code is to show you what it looks like.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <a href="?login.type=enterprise">
        <div class="btn-default">
            Enterprise
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
    <a href="?login.type=cloud">
        <div class="btn-default">
            Cloud
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I would like to click on the cloud via VBA code.. I've got the following which doesn't do the trick.

The following code VBA which is the code I need for my excel VBA.

```
Set links = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each Hyperlink In links
  If InStr(Hyperlink.href, "cloud") Then
     Hyperlink.Click
     Exit For
  End If   
Next
```

Problem is that I can't use the navigate option as it errors on this I really need to click on the button (btn-default) via code.

And the following solution also didn't do the trick

```
Dim ele As Object

For Each ele In IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("btn-default")
    If InStr(ele.innerText, "Cloud") > 0 Then ele.Click
Next
```

Comment: I guess you should post this in the HTML tag, as your question is related to the HTML and it doesn't have any VBA code on it.

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't the code that was wrong just a wrong placement of my code, the following did work after adding a wait to IE:

```
Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

For Each ele In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If InStr(ele.innerText, "Cloud") > 0 Then
        ele.click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure I understood right as you're showing us HTML code but write that you want to use VBA.
Here is a VBA code if you want to create a button on excel that brings you to this link: "?login.type=enterprise"

```
Sub Browse()
 Dim ie As Object
 Set ie = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
 ie.Visible = True
 ie.Navigate "http://example.com/?login.type=enterprise"
End Sub
```

Then you can create a button by going to Developer\Insert\Button and assign it to the above macro by right clicking on it and chose "Assign Macro".

If that's not what you want, please be more precise in your question.

Comment: Sorry for the inaccuracy of my question, I've updated my problem as your solution can't be used unfortunately.

Comment: @Oklmmotsook I see your edit but now you're showing me javascript and asking for VBA solutions so I still don't understand.

Comment: My solution is VBA, see the following "IE.document.getElementsByTagName"

Comment: Then what's the relation with HTML. That's basically what confuses us. Either you use HTML or you use VBA. You can't use both together. If I understood well you have an excel grid with two buttons and every time they click on a button you want them to arrive to ?login.type=icloud. Is that correct?

Comment: The relation with the HTML is to show you what the html source looks like on how to program a solution to click on the button via VBA, I've got an excel file without buttons. I need to automate I process of a login to a site. Everything is working smoothly except for this piece. I can't seem to find how I can click on that button via VBA.

Comment: Ok, I think you should remove that HTML as it's just confusing. Put a screenshot instead. Otherwise, instead of using a button you could use this code to assign a cell as hyperlink: 'Sub sbCreatingHyperLink()
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("A5"), "http://www.example.com?login.type=cloud"
End Sub'

Comment: Or check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191506/internet-explorer-automation-with-vba-input-events

Comment: the problem consists in the following, I can't use the following:

      
Set anchorElement = IE.Document.getElementByClassName("btn-default")(0)
        anchorElement.Click