# Problems Using .value in VBA for Internet Explorer Automation

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I have this code that log in on instagram page. It catches the tag name of the username field and input a value on it (the username of the instagram I wanna log).

Code of Instagram page:

```
input name="username" class="_kp5f7 _qy55y" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="" aria-label="Nome de usuário" type="text" maxlength="30" placeholder="Nome de usuário" value="" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off"
```

**Full Code** (edited by the user, can't edit post)

```
Sub FOLLOW()

Dim IE As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Dim contador, contador2, contador3, lngremoto, turnopar As Integer
Dim numeropages, xopepacounter, usuario, senha, numeroseguir, tipopage As String
Dim numeropaginasseguir, entrarpage As String

usuario = Cells(2, 2).Value
senha = Cells(2, 3).Value

'abrir o IE
IE.Visible = True
apiShowWindow IE.Hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE

'maximizar, caso minimizado
IE.navigate ("www.instagram.com")

'Wait for ie to LOAD
Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
Sleep 1500

'Click on switch accounts
'Set inputcollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
'For Each aelement In inputcollection
   ' If aelement.getAttribute("class") = "_niffh" Then
        'If InStr(aelement.innerText, "Trocar de conta") Then
         'aelement.Click
         'End If
    'End If
'Next

'Click on login button
Set inputcollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each aelement In inputcollection
    If aelement.getAttribute("class") = "_fcn8k" Then
        If InStr(aelement.innerText, "Fa?a login") Then
         aelement.Click
         End If
    End If
Next

'Wait for IE to load
Do While IE.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
Sleep 3000

'Fill the field username
Set inputcollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
For Each aelement In inputcollection
    If aelement.getAttribute("name") = "username" Then
         aelement.Focus
         aelement.Value = usuario
         Sleep 1000
    End If
Next

'Fill the field password
Set inputcollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
For Each aelement In inputcollection
    If aelement.getAttribute("name") = "password" Then
         aelement.Focus
         aelement.Value = senha
         Sleep 1000
    End If
Next

'click on sign in
Set inputcollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")
For Each aelement In inputcollection
    If aelement.getAttribute("class") = "_ah57t _84y62 _7xso1 _rmr7s" Then
        If InStr(aelement.innerText, "Entrar") Then
         aelement.Click
         End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

The problem is that the code isn't filling the field correctly. Visually it looks like its filled on Instagram page, but when you click to log in a message error appear saying that I didn't got the username field filled.

This code is only working with the send keys method, and it does not work for me cause I want to hide the Internet Explorer window.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's almost impossible to debug it, please post the rest of your code, where do you set-up the address, how do you set-up `IE.document`, etc...

Comment: This SO answer to related Q looks promising http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191506/internet-explorer-automation-with-vba-input-events?rq=1#answer-10258397

Comment: @SMeaden its does not helped, already tried to focus on another field

Comment: @ShaiRado posted bellow! Thankk you!!